# elasticsearch cannot read certificate file

Tags: linux, elasticsearch, permissions, file-permissions, certbot

I generated a certificate file with certbot. It is placed in `/etc/letsencrypt/...`.

I created a group called `elk` where I added the `elasticsearch` user, and I recursively set it as the owning group for `/etc/letsencrypt` and recursively set the permissions to `770`.

When I start elasticsearch via `systemctl start elasticsearch.service`, it is not able to read the file? `Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.io.FilePermission" "/etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/fullchain.pem" "read")`

Why is that?

What strategy would you recommend to be able to use the same certificate for elasticsearch and kibana?

Comment: Which distro? Using SELinux or Apparmor?

Comment: Ubuntu on AWS EC2

Comment: Using SELinux or Apparmor?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the following permissions:

1. file permissions
2. folder permissions

In best practice, it's recommended to keep certificates in `/etc/elasticsearch` directory. So I recommend the following steps for linux env.

1. `mkdir /etc/elasticsearch/certs`
2. `cp /etc/letsencrypt/live/<domain>/* /etc/elasticsearch/certs/`
3. `chown elasticsearch:elasticsearch /etc/elasticsearch/certs/ -R`

You can use the same certificate for both kibana and elasticsearch.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/security-basic-setup-https.html#encrypt-kibana-http

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/settings.html

```
elasticsearch.ssl.certificate
elasticsearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities
```

These are used by Kibana to authenticate itself when making outbound SSL/TLS connections to Elasticsearch.

Also please check the similar question [here](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/access-denied-to-certs-when-starting-elasticsearch/210782).